# Powershell script server ping output

Tags: powershell, export, ping

I have not used powershell in some time but still know the basics. I am trying to create a script that out puts a csv  file by checking a hostnames IP address. If the IP address is correct for the hostname it outputs YES. If the IP is wrong for the hostname it outputs NO. I have searched here and also on other sites with no prevail. Here is what I have. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for a great community! :

```
$names = Get-content "hnames.txt"

foreach ($name in $names){
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
    Write-Host "$name,up"
  }
  else{+
    Write-Host "$name,down"
  }
}
```

Comment: i see you fetching content from 'hname.txt' what are you comparing the ip to?

Comment: Well, first of all, pinging the host name does not necessarily tell you that the host name is valid. It just tells you that there is a device at the IP address that matches the IP address in the DNS record for that host name. I deal with stale DNS records on a regular basis. Having said that to get the output you want the canonical powershell way to do that is to create a custom object that has fields for the host name and the test result inside yoour foreach. Add that record to a collection. At the end export the collection to a csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
# example data saved in .\compinfo.csv:
hname,ip
comp1,192.168.1.10
comp2,192.168.1.11

# importing the example data
$compinfo = import-csv .\compinfo.csv

$lookupData = foreach($comp in $compinfo)
{
    $nslkup = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($comp.hname)
    $ping = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $comp.hname -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    if($ping)
    {
        $status = "up"
    }
    else
    {
        $status = "down"
    }
    if($nslkup.AddressList.IPAddressToString -eq $comp.ip)
    {
        $ipgood = $true
    }
    else
    {
        $ipgood = $false
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        computerName = $comp.hname
        expectedIp = $comp.ip
        status = $status
        goodIp = $ipgood
        dnsName = $nslkup.hostname
    }
} 

$lookupData | export-csv .\lookups.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hello @brendan62269,
That looks awesome! I made an edit at like 9 char 30 and changed from $cominfo to $compinfo.

The export of the csx is giving  a weird return however, this is the data in the csv file:
IsReadOnly IsFixedSize IsSynchronized Keys Values SyncRoot Count
FALSE FALSE FALSE System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection System.Object 5
FALSE FALSE FALSE System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection System.Object 5

Comment: what version of powershell do you have? i don't think it should matter but i have 5.1 and other than the typo you mentioned this works for me.

Comment: it was totally the version of PS. good call. i updated  and it looks great.